# How to perform a 2 sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test controlling for a type II error instead of type 1

Tags: statistical-significance, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, type-i-and-ii-errors, two-sample

I have four completely different sets of two samples and want to check for each set if both samples come from the same distribution, so four Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests total. If it's going to be relevant, two sets of distributions look normal, two are skewed.

The critical values table for this test gives alpha significance, but I'm not afraid of rejecting the null hypothesis when it's true, I'm afraid of accepting it when it is false.

I understand it's not possible to conclude decisively that two distributions are the same, but what **can** be done to determine **as well as possible** that there is very little evidence to reject that they are the same?

Answer (score 1):

Type I error (which is not the probability of making an error and should be called Type I assertion probability IMHO) does not have anything to do with your data and sets the effect size to zero, making it easy to compute.  Type II assertion probability depends strongly on the size of the effect you would be embarrassed to miss.  So it’s difficult to compute.  It would be easier and more valuable to plot the K-S simultaneous confidence bands for the difference in any two group’s cumulative distribution functions.

Comment: That sounds good. Do you have any pointers for how to go about plotting simultaneous confidence bands? I'm using Excel. I searched online but haven't found how to do it so far.

Comment: This is covered in nonparametric statistics texts; someone here may be able to summarize.  This involves computing the critical value at say the 0.95 level of the K-S statistic and using that to form a confidence envelope around the empirical cumulative distribution function differences.  It is automatically simultaneous.